# I am trying to use native-base,after installing got this error

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am new to react-native.

After installing native-base third party library on my project got an error:

```
Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto" from "node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\IconNB.js".
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why is this off topic? I think your issue will be solved with "npm i react-native-vector-icons".

Comment: same problem, and not solved with npm install react-native-vector-icons

Comment: Solved!
By Downgrading native-base to : 2.13.10
  "npm install native-base@2.13.10 --save-exact"